# Which secure cloud storage service for developers?

Tags: web-services, security, cloud

I want to create a new service and I need to find a secure cloud storage with client-side encryption. The service needs to be accessible with an API or a SDK or something like that.

I made some researches and I found Mega. Do you know another?

Is there an open source solution to construct this kind of cloud?

Comment: None of them is ok. Parse is for analytics...
I need a secure cloud storage with client-side encryption. I edit my question.

Comment: You can use any major service (Google Drive, S3, Azure, Dropbox) and perform client-side encryption yourself or use CloudBlackbox package of our SecureBlackbox product to do this automagically for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cloud have data storage like.

1. Amazon :- SQS,S3,DynamoDB,RDS etc.
2. Azure :- Blob Storage, DBMS , Table storage etc.

All these storage can be access by API.

You can implement data encryption like Hashing, Symmetric, Asymmetric at client side before storing the data into cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

I work for [Adrenaline Mobility](http://www.adrenalinemobility.com/). We're a new entry into this area, but that's exactly what we do. (Sorry for the promotion, but it's quite relevant). We provide secure storage (client side encryption), credential management (login / signup / password reset), messaging (end-to-end encrypted messages between users, devices, etc). Our architecture is designed so that you don't need to trust us, or our storage backend.